# cannot be called in a class component. React hooks must be called in a react function component or a custom react hook function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Saludos estoy recién aprendiendo React y me topé con este error

```
cannot be called in a class component. React hooks must be called in a react function component or a custom react hook function
```

este es el código

```
  import React, {Component} from "react";

class ComponenteA extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <span>ComponenteA</span>
        )
    }
}
class ComponenteB extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <span>ComponenteB</span>
        )
    }
}

function useConditionalRendering (mostrarA) {
    if (mostrarA){
        return <ComponenteA/>
    }
    return <ComponenteB/>
    
}


export default class ConditionalSection extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={mostrarA:true}
    }
    render (){
        return  (
            <div>
                <h4>Conditional Render</h4>
               {useConditionalRendering(this.state.mostrarA.mostrarA)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

el error me sale en esta línea de código `{useConditionalRendering(this.state.mostrarA.mostrarA)}`
les agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: Quiere decir que los hooks solo se pueden usar en componentes funcionales, no en componentes de clase como el tuyo

Comment: como podría resolverlo porfavor??

Comment: Cambia a un componente funcional, es decir, la clase `ConditionalSection` trátala como componente en vez de ser una clase.

Comment: podrías añadir tu repuesta para saber, porque no entiendo mucho este tema

Comment: Con cambiarle el nombre a la función por algo que no empiece por `use` quitabas el error. Ninguna respuesta es correcta. `React` utiliza la palabra reservada `use` al inicio de las funciones para nombrar los `Hooks`, y va a considerar cualquier función que comience con la palabra `use` como un `hook`. Como los `hooks` no pueden utilizarse en clases, pero React piensa que tu función es un `hook`, por eso te da el error. Cambia el nombre de la función a algo que no empiece con `use` y problema solucionado.

Comment: Adicionalmente pusiste `this.state.mostrarA.mostrarA`, debería ser simplemente `this.state.mostrarA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo te recomiendo cambiar a componentes funcionales. Aún así si quieres renderizar un componente dependiendo de una condición tendría que ser algo así:

```
export default class ConditionalSection extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={mostrarA:true}
}
render (){
    return  (
        <div>
            <h4>Conditional Render</h4>
           {this.state.mostrarA
              ? <ComponenteA />
              : <ComponenteB/ />
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Ya después tienes que controlar mediante una función, las props o el componentDidUpdate, o componentDidMount el valor de mostrarA para que renderice uno u otro

Comment: y si la lógica la quisiera poner en una función como sería???

Comment: En la página en la que llamas a ConditionalSection, le puedes pasar una prop que sea  mostrarA={true} o {false}. quedaría `<ConditionalSection mostrarA={true} />`. También cambiar la condición de renderizado para que en lugar de renderizar por la variable de estado, lo haga en función del valor de la prop, sería `this.props.mostrarA`

Comment: Se podría hacer en este componente con una función pero no se que lógica quieres que tenga

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones, una dejarlo tal cual y colocar otro tipo de validación que no sea el `this.state.mostrarA.mostrarA, la otra opción es dejarlo en componente funcional (recomendado):

De esto:

```
export default class ConditionalSection extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={mostrarA:true}
    }
    render (){
        return  (
            <div>
                <h4>Conditional Render</h4>
               {useConditionalRendering(this.state.mostrarA.mostrarA)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

A esto:

```
const ConditionalSection = () => {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={mostrarA:true}
    }
    render (){
        return  (
            <div>
                <h4>Conditional Render</h4>
               {useConditionalRendering(this.state.mostrarA.mostrarA)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ConditionalSection
```

Si quieres dejarlo como clase en tu validación solo usa esto (no recomendado):

```
{useConditionalRendering(mostrarA)}
```

> Lo mejor es usar componentes funcionales para evitar menos código; además de que facilita el entendimiento de tu código. Para lo único que deberías usar componentes como clases en lugar de componentes funcionales es cuando requieres más funciones de lo usual.